# Field not found: 'NHibernate.NHibernateUtil.String'

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, saga

I am trying to Configure `NHibernate` package `id="NHibernate" version="4.0.0.4000" targetFramework="net451"` with fluent package `id="FluentNHibernate" version="2.0.1.0" targetFramework="net451"`. The following code :

```
var sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
.Database(SQLiteConfiguration.Standard.InMemory)
.Mappings(m =>
{
    m.FluentMappings
    .AddFromAssemblyOf<ExampleSagaMap>();
)
.ExposeConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    chemaExport = new SchemaExport(cfg);
})
.BuildSessionFactory();
```

The map code:

```
public ExampleSagaMap()
{
    Not.LazyLoad();

    Id(x => x.CorrelationId).GeneratedBy.Assigned();

    Map(x => x.CurrentState)
        .Access.ReadOnlyPropertyThroughCamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore)
        .CustomType<StateMachineUserType>();

    Map(x => x.MessagesReceived);
    Map(x => x.MessagesSent);
}
```

The error :

> An invalid or incomplete configuration was used while creating a
>   SessionFactory. Check PotentialReasons collection, and InnerException
>   for more detail.
>
> Inner error: {"Field not found: 'NHibernate.NHibernateUtil.String'."}

Can someone please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was getting this error because I had implemented a custom enum type using `IUserType` that was referencing `NHibernateUtil.String.SqlType`.

The solution was to use the new `SqlTypeFactory` instead.

```
/* Used by NHibernate to cast between string and type-safe-enum */
public class MyCustomEnumType : IUserType
{

    ...

    public SqlType[] SqlTypes
    {
        get { 
            return new[] {                   
                // not working for NHibernate 4.1
                //NHibernateUtil.String.SqlType 
                SqlTypeFactory.GetString(200)
            }; 
        }
    }        

    ...
}
```